# Finding best match in mongoengine database with Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

Suppose we have a a Django model similar to this:

```
from mongoengine import (Document, StringField, DateTimeField)

class MyModel(Document):
    car = StringField()
    plane = StringField()
    name = StringField()
    some_field = SecretField()
    date = DateTimeField()
    # some more fields ...
```

Then, we want to take *best matching object* from our database for a given set of parameters, for example

```
@classmethod
def desired_method(cls, **kwargs):
    # for a given kwargs, choose the one that have fields in db
    # and return object for that parameter (ordered by date, say last one)
```

For example, calling `MyModel.desired_method(car='Ford', name='Bettsy')` would return last object created in db, with Ford car having name Bettsy.

On the other hand, calling `MyModel.desired_method(plane='Airbus', some_field='hashed_msg', pilot='Ron', age='7')` would return last object with specified `plane` and `some_field` fields, but others are ignored, as they do not exists in our model.

The purpose for all that is to be able to flexible extend functionality - let's say we are using model to add new objects to db, with specified `car`, `name` and `some_field` fields. With some populated db, we got request from client to start distinguish objects by another field `version`. We can't do it backwards, but we may add field `version` to our model, populate db with new entries, and change code in application from:

```
my_car = return_car()
my_name = return_name()
result = MyModel.desired_method(car=my_car, name=my_name)
```

to:

```
my_car = return_car()
my_name = return_name()
my_version = return_version()
result = MyModel.desired_method(car=my_car, name=my_name, version=my_version)
```

such that if we call `MyModel.desired_method(car='Ford', name='Bettsy',version='123')` we still get object for a given `car` and `name`, even if given entry does not have `version` (it was not in the model while adding to db - backward compatibility).

More generally, solution could be create a model with dynamically added fields - so for example

```
new_item = MyModel(name='John Doe', age='90')
new_item.save()
```

would create a new field `age` in the model, but I don't know if it is even possible

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? to have a generic model type, which could accomodate multiple kinds of objects??

Answer (score 0):

```
In [12]: class MyModel(Document):
    ...:     car = StringField()
    ...:     plane = StringField()
    ...:     name = StringField()
    ...:     some_field = StringField()
    ...:     date = DateTimeField()
    ...:     @queryset_manager
    ...:     def desired_method(cls, queryset, **kwargs):
    ...:         return queryset(**kwargs)
    ...:     

In [13]: MyModel.desired_method(car='Ford', name='Betsy')
Out[13]: []

In [14]: car = MyModel(car='Ford', name='Betsy').save()

In [15]: MyModel.desired_method(car='Ford', name='Betsy')
Out[15]: [<MyModel: MyModel object>]
```

does that answer your question?

Comment: it will raise InvalidQueryError when you pass non-existsing field